# Unable to execute java class file from php exec method?

Tags: java, php

I am trying to execute a java class file from php using the exec method. However, i get the following error.

I have set chmod 777 to the java class file so i suppose permission is not an issue.

For some reason it is not able to find it ?

I can run the java class file from the terminal using the java command without any problem

Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .var.www.redbutton.readBashScript.class


<?php

exec('java /var/www/redbutton/readBashScript.class');

?>
```

and

```
<?php

exec('java /var/www/redbutton/readBashScript');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java exec does not work like that.

You need not pass the file to "execute", but the class which is why you get an error.

You must do:

```
java -cp /var/www/redbutton readBashScript
```

But:

- `/var/www/redbutton` must be a classpath directory, where your .class reside. Java will by default try to find classes in the current directory, which explains why it work in the console.
- `readBashScript` must be the name of a class containing a `main` method.